# File creation using an app on server initiated with SSH command running via bash script

Tags: command-line, server, bash, scripts, ssh

I have an app on my server which creates log files when running. I have to run this application from my local machine using a script. So in my script I use SSH command to execute my app on the server.

```
ssh user@serverIP "/application_dir/myapp -i ./config -o ./Logs/" &
```

Even though the app runs it cannot create these log files. I have tried giving full access premonitions to the log folder and the problem still occurs.

I hope someone can help to resolve the issue and thanks in advance.

Comment: @user68186 I am using Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: @user68186 no it does not work that way either

Comment: Perhaps "the a-p-p" just dosn't work. How should we know anyway?

Comment: @ mikewhatever I know the app works fine because if I directly log in to the server pc and run the application it will create these log files

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1066192/edit) your question and add the new information in the question. From your comment it looks like if you use `ssh user@serverIP` to login to the server and then enter the command `/application_dir/myapp -i ./config -o ./Logs/` then the log files are not created. However, if you directly log in to the server pc and run the application it will create the log files. In your question write exactly what commands you type to run the app. Also indicate the current folder where the terminal is open when you enter the command.